# Silverlight deep zoom image click issue

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, silverlight, deepzoom

I am using deep zoom composer to generate XAP and html files and they works fine for me. Currently, I want to retrieve the information about which image the end user is clicked, and I want to display the description information for the user clicked image in another Silverlight TextBox control on the same page. The description informaiton is currently stored in a database, and has WCF interface. So, I need to know which image in the whole deep zoom area is clicked (support I have 100 images, 10 images in a row and 10 rows).

Any reference samples or documents? I am using Silverlight 2.0 + VSTS 2008 + .Net + C# + IIS 7.0 on Windows Vista x86 Enterprise.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1):

projectsilverlight [Wilfred Pinto](http://projectsilverlight.blogspot.com/2008/03/dissecting-hard-rock-memorabilia-and_8725.html) posted  interesting solution to find the image index of the selected image. go check out here

I used the index to loop through the MetaData.xml collection to find the tags associated image..